# PowerShell - Select-Object when the column header has a dynamic name

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am reading an CSV File in which, depending on the month, the column headers will have different names. They will always represent 3 months ago, 2 months ago, and 1 month ago, but will have column header names such as:

- Actuals(-3) Reg Hrs Oct-22
- Actuals(-2) Reg Hrs Nov-22
- Actuals(-1) Reg Hrs Dec-22

For my needs, I need to rename these columns to something generic, such as:

- Actuals(-3) Reg Hrs
- Actuals(-2) Reg Hrs
- Actuals(-1) Reg Hrs

This is to be able to support an upload to a pre-configured schema.

Is there a way I can use a regular expression to "select" these columns, and rename them?

Here is what I currently have:

```
    Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | 
        where {$_."Cost Center" -eq "ABC123"} | 
        Select-Object @{ expression={$_."Actuals(-3) Reg Hrs Oct-22"}; label='3 Months Ago Regular' } | 
        Export-Csv -notype $csvFile2
```

Obviously, this code example is looking for the actual column name, but I am wondering if I can use regular expressions here to match the static part. (assume there will be no ambiguity in the file)

Thanks!

Comment: Are the columns always in the same place? You could define your headers when you import the CSV like `Import-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv -Headers 'Name','EmployeeID','1 Month Ago Regular','2 Months Ago Regular','3 Months Ago Regular'`

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician! That worked (except it was -Header, without the plural).